# Pandas dataframe of sum from lists

Tags: python, pandas

Good afternoon!
I need to add intervals from a list and make a pandas dataframe and load the data into a DB. There was a problem with the amount. I need to add all the timestamps from one list and get the sum and then create another column called Time by assignee Client and insert it into the DB, but I can't figure out how to add them ('198:18:57' + '0:0:0' and etc).

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://jira_user:jira_user@localhost:5432/jira_test')
data = [['CRT-33', '198:18:57', '0:0:0', '0:0:0', '0:0:0', '0:0:0', 'CRT-369'], ['CRT-34', '0:0:0', '0:0:0', '0:0:0', '0:0:0', '167:17:22','CRT-355']]
header = ["Key", "Time_in_Resolved", "Time_in_InfoRequest", "Time_in_Postponed","Time_in_PM_Review","Time_in_Rejected"]
data_c = []
data_sum=[]

#delete last value from query
for i in data:
    data_c.append((i[:-1]))
#delete first colum for calculating
for i in data_c:
    data_sum.append((i[1:]))
#the sum of all data from the list ? 

print(data_c)
dat = DataFrame(data_c, columns=header)
dat.to_sql('correction_an', con=engine, schema='public', index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: can you add your sample expected output?

Comment: for example
['198:18:57', '0:0:0', '0:0:0', '0:0:0', '2:0:0']
in output (after sum of objects in lists)
['200:18:57']
in DataFrame
 Key       Time by assignee Client   Time_in_Resolved Time_in_InfoRequest Time_in_Postponed  Time_in_PM_Review    Time_in_Rejected  
0  CRT-33  200:18:57       198:18:57               0:0:0             0:0:0               0:0:0              0:0:0                2:0:0